# Price is being overwritten despite different conditions $this->price;

Tags: symfony, scope

I am a newbie using Symfony v2.0 and I'm wondering why is my final price being overwritten despite the fact I use different `if` aspects. Final price uses only the last used `$this->price` and confuses my price calculators for example:

```
if ($this->mode == 'coaching')
                {

                $n = $this->orderDetails->{'hours-number'};
                if($n == 1)
                    $this->price = 5;
                else if($n == 2)
                    $this->price = 35;
                else if($n == 3)
                    $this->price = 45;
                else if($n == 4)
                    $this->price = 55;
                else if($n == 5)
                    $this->price = 65;

                $this->eta = '1 Day';

                $w = 0;

                if ($this->orderDetails->{'option'} == 'wins')
                {
                    $w = $this->orderDetails->{'wins-number'} * 2;
                    $this->price = $w;

                }
                $p = 0;

                if ($this->orderDetails->{'option'} == 'self')
                {
                    $p = $this->orderDetails->{'wins-number'} * 2.5;
                    $this->price = $p;

                }
```

The final `$this->price` will be displayed only, despite the fact that 'hours-numbers' is being called only. Shall I write the code differently while I have multiple conditions affecting the price?

I also have my functions written in `index.html.twig` :

```
function updateOrderArray()
        {
            var nData = {};

            $('*[pp-type="item"]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox')
                {
                    nData[ $(this).attr('pp-item-name') ] = $(this).is(':checked');
                }
                else
                {
                    nData[ $(this).attr('pp-item-name') ] = $(this).val();
                }
            });

            var nJSON = JSON.stringify(nData);
            $('input[name="order_details"]').val(nJSON);


            checkDivisions();
            calculatePrice();
        }

        function calculatePrice()
        {
            $('#arena-price').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            $('#arena-eta').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{ path('service_price') }}',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    mode: 'coaching',
                    order_details: $('input[name="order_details"]').val()
                }
            })
```

Comment: Could you maybe show an example of what the incoming data, i.e. `$this->orderDetails` looks like and maybe what kind of result you expect? Your code looks a bit weird, especially the dynamically accessed attributes like `$this->orderDetails->{'hours-number'}`. Are you sure that `$n` has the value you expect or that `$this->orderDetails->{'option'}` returns either of both values?

Comment: I am a total newbie so I dont even use a console. How do I get a console to work, any program preffered?   $n is correct. Attaching my functions for the price.

Comment: You can use `dump($n)` or `dd($n)` anywhere in your code. The first generates the output of the variable and then continues with the code and the latter will dump + die, so it will stop the code after outputting the variable, meaning the following lines are not executed.

Comment: You can just do a `dd($this->orderDetails)` right before the code snippet or st the top, inside your outermost if-condition and then paste the output here. Make sure that this does not contain sensitive information.

Comment: ok i got my console to work but cant dump stuff, will read more about it. Although it just hit me, calculatePrice() function has data: in it with mode: coaching. Can i freely add a new lets say type: 'oneperson', 'twoperson' and then use these two in my price changing file? like if ($this->type->'oneperson') will it work?